# Problem of Java.util.Date in numeric format is resteasy client

Tags: java, json, date, glassfish, resteasy

There is a sample of resteasy rest api.

Part of pom.xml:

```xml
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey DI and core-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>hk2-metadata-generator</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- add jackson as json provider -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and the part of my resource class:

```java
@Path("/test")
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Date test() {
    return new Date();
}
```

So when I request `http://localhost:8080/test`, the response is `1685343320152` instead of date format.

Where is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can address part of your Question, explaining why the response is `1685343320152`.

## Default is count from epoch

Apparently, Jackson defaults to serializing a `java.util.Date` object to a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 as seen in UTC (1970-01-01T00:00Z).

## ISO 8601

Better to serialize to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Use `ObjectMapper` to change the format from that default to ISO 8601.

```java
// Source code from: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-dates
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper() ;
mapper.disable( SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS ) ;
mapper.setDateFormat( new StdDateFormat().withColonInTimeZone( true ) ) ;
```

See [*Jackson Date*](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-dates) by baeldung.

## *java.time*

You are using terribly flawed date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Specifically, `java.util.Date` was replaced by [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). Both represent a moment as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC, but with a resolution of milliseconds versus nanoseconds respectively.

I strongly suggest you consider replacing your use of the legacy classes with the modern ones.

Comment: How to config this mapper in grizzly server?

Comment: @rezaramezanimatin That part is above my pay grade.

Comment: I do not understand how to config mapper in grizzly server side?

Comment: Another hand I am not able to config the modelmapper in grizzly correctly

Comment: It is solved by registration mapper config in grizzly